# A function object can't draw images to an image from a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

The title is poorly worded but there's no way to concisely describe the problem. I'm drawing images to the 2D context of a dynamically created canvas. The data of the context is then saved to an image via `toDataURL`, which is then draw on every frame. The code below is condensed, I will be drawing multiple images to the context, not just one; which is why I'm saving to an image. I will only draw part of the image at once but the image remains constant so I thought this was the best method, if there are alternatives I will happily accept those as answers.

In short: many images drawn on an image. Part of the image draw each frame. 
The code below works:

```js
var picture = new Image();
picture.src = "images/tilesheet.png";
var canvas = document.getElementById("background");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
function generate(){
 var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = canvas.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = canvas.height;
 ctx.fillStyle = "red"; 
 ctx.rect (0, 0, 40, 40);
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.drawImage(picture,0,0);
 image = new Image();
 image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  
}
function draw(){
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 context.drawImage(image, 0,0,100,100,0,0,100,100); 
}
function play(){
  generate();
  setInterval(function(){draw();}, 0.0333);
}
window.onload = function(){
 if(picture.complete)play();
 else picture.onload = play; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="background"></canvas>
```

However this doesn't:

```js
window.Game = {};
canvas = document.getElementById("background");
var tilesheet = new Image();
tilesheet.src = "images/tilesheet.png";
(function(){
 function Map(){
  this.width = 2736;
  this.height = 2736;
  this.image = null;
 }
 Map.prototype.generate = function(){
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
   ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
   ctx.canvas.height = this.height;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"; 
  ctx.rect (0, 0, 40, 40);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.drawImage(tilesheet,0,0);
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
  this.image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");     
 }
 Map.prototype.draw = function(context){             
  context.drawImage(this.image, 0,0, context.canvas.height, context.canvas.height, 0, 0, context.canvas.height, context.canvas.height);   
 }
 Game.Map = Map;
})();
(function(){
 var room = new Game.Map();
 room.generate();
 var draw = function(){
  canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
  room.draw(canvas.getContext("2d"));  
 }
 Game.play = function(){setInterval(function(){draw();}, 0.0333);}
})();
window.onload = function(){
 if(tilesheet.complete)Game.play();
 else tilesheet.onload = Game.play; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="background"></canvas>
```

It seems therefore, that the problem is lying in the fact that I'm using function objects but I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong? There are no errors in the debug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two have different execution order.

First one:

1. ...
2. Attach `image.onload`

   1. **Call `generate()`**
   2. ...

Second one:

1. ...
2. **Call `generate()`**
3. Attach `image.onload`

   1. ...

That's why it's not working - `generate()` expects image to be loaded, however second case order doesn't guarantees it.

Instead of

```
...
room.generate();
...
Game.play = function(){setInterval(function(){draw();}, 0.0333);}
```

do this

```
...
Game.play = function(){
    room.generate();
    setInterval(function(){draw();}, 0.0333);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works :) But I'm confused as to why... Surely if `room.generate();` isn't called then neither is `var room = new Game.Map();`? Which would cause an undefined exception... No?

Comment: The problem is `room.generate()` is called too early - image could not be ready yet, becouse it's not being called in `onload` of image it uses.